# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryMethodInvocationListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

Hi' I'm trying to add an actuator dependency in my pom. But While running the app it is failing with error: **2022-01-25 08:55:37,795 [main]           ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication []:: Application run failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration.metricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener**

pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**logs:**

```
2022-01-25 08:55:37,795 [main]           ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication []:: Application run failed 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration.metricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)  
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at com.sap.srfaas.SpringBootApp.main(SpringBootApp.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:487)   
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:436)     
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142) 
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)  
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration.metricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:517)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:506)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:429)     
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryMethodInvocationListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:513)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvocationListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
2022-01-25 08:55:37,808 [main]           WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication []:: Unable to close ApplicationContext 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886)      
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:874)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at com.sap.srfaas.SpringBootApp.main(SpringBootApp.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryMethodInvocationListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvocationListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: please specify spring boot version in order to recreate it

Answer (score 3):

The class `org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvocationListener`
is present in the jar : `spring-data-commons`

As per javadoc https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/latest/index.html
this Class is introduced since version : `2.4.0`

Check if you have any older version ( < `2.4.0`) of above jar in pom.xml. If present remove it if you have `spring-boot-starter` dependency (it will automatically add the desired version) else ensure that you have version >`2.4.0`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```